# What shapes can be gears?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

I am interested in gears. Sadly most of the writing on this is very practical and does not get into abstract theory. I have been trying to formalize these ideas to be able to ask what shapes can function as gears and at what ratios. I have had two attempts to formalize this question.

For my first formalization we can think of the functions $f:[0,2\pi) \to (0,\infty)$ as defining the gears outlined by the polar expression $r=f(\theta)$. My question becomes for what values $a\in [0,\infty)$ is there a function $g:[0,2\pi) \to (0,\infty)$ that generates a gear that meshes with our first gear and rotates $a$ times for every time the first gear rotates. I included $0$ as a possible value of $a$ to represent [linear gears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_gear). This formalization falls short because it only looks at particular shapes. In this formalization it is also difficult to define what it means for two gears to mesh.

For my second and preferred formalization we think of a gear as an ordered pair $G = (X,c)$ where $X$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}^2$. This is meant to represent the gear made of the points in $X$ that rotates around the point $c$. The set $X$ is not necessarily connected and $c$ is not necessarily in $X$ because of objects like [lantern gears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lantern_gear). There are a lot of ways to formalize a rotation. I chose to use elements of $S^1$ and apply them to the gear object. Now given the gears $G_1$ and $G_2$ their meshing space is $\{(a,b) \in S^1 \times S^1\mathrel\vert aG_1\cap bG_2 = \emptyset\}$. It is interesting to note that $S^1 \times S^1$ is the torus. So the question from before becomes whether or not there are continuous functions from $S^1$ to this subset of the torus, and if so how many and members and of what homotopy classes.

Edit:
There are a lot of questions that could be asked about the meshing space. One could be dimensionality. If the space is made of one-dimensional curves that means the gears line up perfectly. If the space is for example the whole torus that means the gears do not touch each other at all. Also upon further playing around, I think it makes more sense to have $X$ be open and bounded. If $X$ is closed then by the intersection condition the gears could not touch each other. This also removes situations with single disconnected points.

I was wondering if anyone had an answer to my question, under either formalization, or had a smarter way to formalize this question.

Comment: I proofread a bit, but I wasn't quite sure what to make of "how many and members and of what homotopy classes"; maybe you could clarify? \\ Your formalisation seems to distinguish between, say, the 'outline' of a gear and the 'filled-in' gear; do you wish to do that? \\ Does $a G_1$ mean to regard $a$ as a complex number and $G_1 - c$ as a set of complex numbers, and multiply them thus?

Comment: An earlier question, [Optimal Gear Trains](https://mathoverflow.net/q/109343/6094), cites an [AMS column](http://www.ams.org/publicoutreach/feature-column/fcarc-stern-brocot), which connects to "Clock making and the Stern-Brocot tree." This may lead to other literature.

Comment: Another related question: [Solving for special rational triangles](https://mathoverflow.net/q/134676/6094).

Comment: I thought perhaps you could make gears with cross-section a curve with constant width but this does not work in a straight forward manner as the axles would need to be able to move horizontally, and usually gears do not allow that. But supposing that they could, then this should work.

Comment: You probably need more restrictions (in the second version): if the meshing space in your sense is the whole torus, you will have all the maps you want, but the gears would not work since they will never touch each other

Comment: To fix  მამუკა ჯიბლაძე's comment: perhaps one should ask that the meshing space, rather than merely containing continuous images of $S^1$, be a manifold homeomorphic to $S^1$.

Comment: Thanks to მამუკა ჯიბლაძე. I added an edit. I think changing to talking about open sets fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks, LSpice. I added an edit to try to clarify. One problem I have been having is how to address the case when gears can mesh in more than one way. This is when the meshing space is disconnected. Also using complex numbers is a way to talk about it. Your formalization is what I mean. I am not committed to an interpretation. There are many ways to represent a rotation so I left that part somewhat vague.

Comment: Allowing the axis to move may be a way to generalize this question further. There are certainly examples of systems like this in real life. Just using curves with constant with is not a great method because they do not have teeth. For example, a perfect circle makes an awful gear because nothing can spin it without the use of friction.

Comment: I have seen gears that I'm pretty certain can't be written as $r = f(\theta)$, as the teeth are a little bulbous.

Comment: Thanks, Arthur I agree. That Is why I came up with the second formalization.

Comment: @Spencer Woolfson: Err, I was expecting people to understand that the curve in question would be 'teethed'. In the same way that one can describe the usual cog as a circular cog since it is a circle that has been 'teethed'.

Comment: How would you "teeth" the curve? It is not at all obvious to me how to add teeth to a curve such that it functions as a gear. Adding the teeth so that the gears mesh is the main part of my question.

Comment: Most concave polygons can be "teethed" in a way to make them a functional gear.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking the same, that concave shapes can act as gears but it seems that concave ones can too. That you were mostly thinking about teething the cogs so that they mesh properly wasn't clear from the question as you were talking about 'shapes' - at least in the headline question.

Comment: @Arthur Sorry, could not resist: https://youtu.be/V3ZSMQE3V0w

Answer (score 6):

if you look for [non-circular gear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-circular_gear) you at least find the wiki article that also addresses the mathematics; there are also links to publication on the subject.

Comment: That's a helpful link! Just as a note: this page and its references address only the first formalism in the question (gear shape as function in polar coordinates).

Comment: the teeth of fears are most commonly via evolvents and I'd be surprised if other kinds of teeth were use for "technical" gears; there is a nice explanation (unfortunately only in German) of[ how to construct the teeth](https://www.tec-science.com/de/getriebe-technik/evolventenverzahnung/evolventen-zahnrad-geometrie/).